# Finding index in list in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to find correct index in a array by comparing ranges. Here is my first try:

```
int TunerDriver::TunerLookUpTable(double Freq) {
  Freq /= 1e6;
  if (Freq >= 60 and Freq < 140)
    return 1;
  else if (Freq >= 180 and Freq < 280)
    return 2;
  else if (Freq >= 280 and Freq < 460)
    return 3;
  else if (Freq >= 140 and Freq < 180)
    return 4;
  else if (Freq >= 2720 and Freq < 4020)
    return 5;
  else if (Freq >= 4020 and Freq <= 6000)
    return 6;
  else if (Freq >= 2000 and Freq < 2720)
    return 7;
  else if (Freq >= 830 and Freq < 1420)
    return 8;
  else if (Freq >= 1420 and Freq < 2000)
    return 9;
  else if (Freq >= 460 and Freq < 830)
    return 10;
  else {
    //TODO: throw exception
  }
}
```

I believe I can use `std::pair` and `for` to increase readability. Can you assist me in this case?

Comment: You could more simply use `std::map()` and/or `std::lower_bound()`.  But you really need to improve the question - *why* do you need to do this lookup?  What do the return values actually *mean*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a short bit of code, but enough to work with, I think.  Here are some suggestions to help you improve your code.

### Minimize the number of comparisons

There is not really a need to check both upper and lower bounds for each possibility if the comparisons are done in order.  That is, we could compare the incoming `Freq` to 60, then 140, then 180, etc.  That might look like this:

```
int FreqLookup(double Freq) {
    if (Freq < 60e6 || Freq > 6000e6) {
        return 0;  // or throw an error
    }
    if (Freq < 140e6) return 1;
    if (Freq < 180e6) return 4;
    if (Freq < 280e6) return 2;
    if (Freq < 460e6) return 3;
    if (Freq < 830e6) return 10;
    if (Freq < 1420e6) return 8;
    if (Freq < 2000e6) return 9;
    if (Freq < 2720e6) return 7;
    if (Freq < 4020e6) return 5;
    return 6;
}
```

### Put constants in a structure

Having the constants in a structure allows the code to be more data driven.  Here's what I'd suggest:

```
struct FreqTableEntry {
    double freq;
    int divisor;
    operator double() const { return freq; }
}; 
static constexpr std::array<FreqTableEntry, 11> lookup {{
    { 60e6, 0 }, // error if below 60e6
    { 140e6, 1 },
    { 180e6, 4 },
    { 280e6, 2 },
    { 460e6, 3 },
    { 830e6, 10 },
    { 1420e6, 8 },
    { 2000e6, 9 },
    { 2720e6, 7 },
    { 4020e6, 5 },
    { 6000e6, 6 },
}};
```

Now we have a nice, neat, compile-time lookup table.  Note also that we can avoid division by simply using the full value in the table.

### Use a standard algorithm

The [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) algorithm returns an iterator to the first entry that is greater than the given value.  We can use it:

```
auto it{std::upper_bound(lookup.cbegin(), lookup.cend(), Freq)};
```

It would be nice to simply return `it->divisor` but we have to handle a few special cases.  First, if the frequency is exactly 6000e6, we need to return 6.  Next, if the frequency is < 60e6 or > 6000e6, we need to indicate an error.  I've chosen to return 0 as an indication of error, but one could also `throw` if that's more appropriate.  Putting it all together we have this:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int alt(double Freq) {
    struct FreqTableEntry {
        double freq;
        int divisor;
        operator double() const { return freq; }
    }; 
    static constexpr std::array<FreqTableEntry, 11> lookup {{
        { 60e6, 0 }, // error if below 60e6
        { 140e6, 1 },
        { 180e6, 4 },
        { 280e6, 2 },
        { 460e6, 3 },
        { 830e6, 10 },
        { 1420e6, 8 },
        { 2000e6, 9 },
        { 2720e6, 7 },
        { 4020e6, 5 },
        { 6000e6, 6 },
    }};
    // special case the last entry
    if (Freq == lookup.back().freq) {
        return lookup.back().divisor;
    }
    auto it{std::upper_bound(lookup.cbegin(), lookup.cend(), Freq)};
    if (it == lookup.cend() || it->divisor == 0) { 
        return 0;  // could throw here as alternative
    }
    return it->divisor;
}
```

### Provide a test program

It's often helpful to write a test program and to provide it to reviewers to make it clear what the program is expected to do and how it will be called.  I modified your routine slightly to return 0 as an error indication and made it a standalone function.  The test program in this case, was just to compare the original routine to the alternative (named `alt`) shown above:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (double f{30e6}; f <= 6020e6; f += 10e6) {
        if (TunerLookUpTable(f) != alt(f)) {
            std::cout << "ERROR: TunerLookUpTable(" << f/1e6 << " MHz) = " 
                << TunerLookUpTable(f) << ", but alt(f) = " << alt(f) << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first code block differs from the original if passed a NaN (returns 6 rather than 0 or throw). The subsequent examples look okay.

Comment: That would be a useful condition to add to a test program.